# How to update TextField value after debounce

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Suppose I am using the following code.

```
class TextFieldObserver : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var realText = ""
    @Published var searchText = ""
    
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(tester: Binding<String>) {
        $searchText
            .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { t in
                self.realText = t
            } )
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
    
    func updateDebounced() {
        realText = "this is a test"
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObseredObject var observer: TextFieldObserver
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Search text", $observer.searchText)
            Button("Update debounced text", action: {observer.updateDebounced()})
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how I can update the variable `observer.searchText` when calling `observer.updateDebounced()` (i.e. I want to update searchText after updating realText since realText represents the text stored in the model and searchText is just an intermediate value).

Comment: `searchText` updates `realText` after the debounce. And you want to update `searchText` after `realText` updates? `realText` should have the same value as `searchText` after the debounce, no?

Comment: I mean if I update `realText` programmatically, `searchText` doesn't update.

Comment: Well, there's no code that updates it. Just set its value along with `realText`